# How can I fix my serial communication from Arduio Uno to ESP8266?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm testing the Serial Communication with my Arduino and NodeMCU, and how I can send one data to another. Here is the Code.

For the Arduino Uno

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); //RX, TX

float i = 10;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("Number ");
  Serial.print(i);
  Serial.println("");
  mySerial.write(i);
  delay(1000);
}
```

And here is for my ESP8266 NodeMCU

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial myNode(D1, D2); //RX, TX

float git;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  myNode.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  git = Serial.read();
  Serial.print("The Number is ");
  Serial.print(git);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
}
```

The result should be that in the Serial Monitor it should say "The Number is 10". But instead it says -1.00 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B432M.png)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've tried but now nothing is showing up in the NODEMCU NodeMCU 
``` #include <SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial myNode(6, 5); //RX, TX

float git;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  myNode.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (myNode.available() > 0) {
  git = myNode.read();
  
  Serial.print("The Number is ");
  Serial.print(git);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I finally figured it out. Apparently I need to initialize the NodeMCU Pin's as so:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

static const uint8_t D1   = 5;
static const uint8_t D2   = 4;
SoftwareSerial myNode(D1, D2); //RX, TX

float git;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  myNode.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  git = Serial.read();
  Serial.print("The Number is ");
  Serial.print(git);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git = myNode.read();
```

instead of

```
git = Serial.read();
```

And check myNode.available() before reading